# can anyone help me,i can't see the output when fetching the data from object in a lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, wire

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="AllContacts">
        <ul>
            <template if:true={responseReceived}>

                <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                <p key={contact.id}>
                        {contact.lastname}
                </p>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template if:false={msg}></template>
        </ul>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import getAllContacts from '@salesforce/apex/Message.getInpMessage'
export default class AccountManagerApex extends LightningElement {
@track contacts;
    @wire(getAllContacts) 
    contacts;
    msg="error";
    get responseReceived(){
        if(this.accounts){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class Message {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<contact> getInpMessage() {
        return [select id,lastname from contact];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding wire to `contacts` variable, but you are checking `this.accounts` in `responseReceived`

Alter you `responseReceived` method

```
get responseReceived(){
        if(this.contacts){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also LWC is case sensitive. Thus Id and Lastname should have proper case

```
<p key={contact.Id}>
     {contact.Lastname}
</p>
```

Comment: I was going to answer this  .. hehe :D btw yea this may be the solution. :)

Comment: `get responseReceived(){ return !!this.contacts; }` would be the standard way of doing this check in JavaScript.